# Returning map to previous state

Tags: google-street-view

I have created a simple map page that is designed to show the locations of various railway photographs using a custom pin on the map. If you hover over the pin, it describes the pin, if you click on it, it opens an info-window containing a series of links to photographs.

I have two issues, one that if you click on the link, then after viewing the photograph you click the back button, the map goes back to a fully zoomed out position again, whereas I would prefer it stayed zoomed in to the position the viewer had left it.

The second issue is that if the viewer uses the Streetview function, it does not have anyway of escaping that function, i.e. there is no back button. I write in Dreamweaver, and if I preview the code in Dreamweaver, Streetview DOES have a back button, yet once I upload the code to my site, it does not. I am puzzled by these different reactions, even though I am using the same browser in both cases.

How can I resolve these issues?

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Photo Sites</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.358548, 144.697350),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);

// Wrecking Train
// From here..                              
  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Overhead Wrecking Train</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>The Overhead Wrecking Train</b> was photographed as it passed through Bunyip ' +
      'in December 2012, dismantling the overhead equipment on the Gippsland line. The train '+
      'is shown just west of the level crossing in Bunyip.'+
      '<p>Photographs: '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/wrecking%20train%201.jpg">'+
      'Wrecking Train 1</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/wrecking%20train%202.jpg">'+
      'Wrecking Train 2</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/wrecking%20train%203.jpg">'+
      'Wrecking Train 3</a> '+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.098461, 145.714411);
  var HollyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'Overhead Wrecking Train'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,HollyMarker);
  });
// To here.


// Bendigo
// From here..
// Do not forget the variables that need a number after them below                              
  var contentString1 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Bendigo Engine Shed</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Bendigo Engine Shed Precincts</b> was photographed in April 2004 when the site was ' +
      'under the control of Southern Shorthaul Railroad, and there were many odd vehicles in the '+
      'yard and some interesting relics in the vicinity of the shed.'+
      '<p>Photographs: '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/7RT on turntable.jpg">'+
      '7RT on Turntable in Shed</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/B class 2.jpg">'+
      'B Class Shell</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/B class bogie 1.jpg">'+
      'B Class Bogie Frame</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/B class bogies.jpg">'+
      'B Class Bogie Frames</a> '+ 
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/D3 619.jpg">'+
      'D3 619</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/Ex SAR Blurbird.jpg">'+
      'Ex SAR Bluebird</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/GM 6 cylinder engine.jpg">'+
      'GM 6 cylinder engine</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/GM 8 cylinder engine.jpg">'+
      'GM 8 cylinder engine</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/GM 16 cylinder engine.jpg">'+
      'GM 16 cylinder engine</a> '+   
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/RT54 ex Portland.jpg">'+
      'RT54 ex Portland</a> '+        
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/RT50 Shunting Yard.jpg">'+
      'RT50 Shunting the Yard</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/H2 and H5.jpg">'+
      'H2 and H5 in the Yard</a> '+           
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  // Increment the variables below for each instance of this routine.
  // The variables are: infowindow, myLatLng and Hollymarker
  var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString1
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.767630, 144.281140);
  var HollyMarker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng1,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'Bendigo Engine Shed Precincts'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker1, 'click', function() {
    infowindow1.open(map,HollyMarker1);
  });
// To here.

// Newport Workshops ARHS Museum Area
// From here..
// Do not forget the variables that need a number after them below                              
  var contentString2 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">ARHS Museum Early 60s</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>The ARHS Museum at Newport</b> was photographed in the early 60s before the area was enclosed. ' +
      'At this time, the area consisted of little more than a track holding several locomotives'+
      '<p>Photographs: '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/H220 Newport early 60s.jpg">'+
      'H220 at ARHS Museum site at Newport in the early 60s</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/X36 Newport early 60s.jpg">'+
      'X36 at ARHS Newport, early 60s</a> '+     
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/Locos Newport early 60s.jpg">'+
      'Heritage Steam Locos at ARHS Newport, early 60s</a> '+    
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  // Increment the variables below for each instance of this routine.
  // The variables are: infowindow, myLatLng Hollymarker and contentString
  var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString2
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.853894, 144.883461);
  var HollyMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng2,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'ARHS Museum Early 60s'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker2, 'click', function() {
    infowindow2.open(map,HollyMarker2);
  });
// To here.

// Newport Workshops Storage Yard
// From here..
// Do not forget the variables that need a number after them below                              
  var contentString3 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Newport Workshops in the early 60s.</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>The yards at Newport Workshops</b> had many interesting items stored there in the early 60s. ' +
      'However film was an expensive commodity to me in those days, so these shots are a mystery as to '+
      'why they were photographed while other items were not. As is often the case, I wish I had spent '+
      'more film on shooting this amazing place.'+    
      '<p>Photographs: '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/7A on transporter at Newport Workshops early 60s.jpg">'+
      '7A on transporter at Newport Workshops early 60s</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/NB on wagon Newport early 60s.jpg">'+
      'NB on wagon Newport early 60s</a> '+  
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/NBCs on wagon at Newport.jpg">'+
      'NBCs on wagon at Newport, early 60s</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/Wooden wagon Newport early 60s.jpg">'+
      'Wooden wagon at Newport early 60s</a> '+       
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  // Increment the variables below for each instance of this routine.
  // The variables are: infowindow, myLatLng and Hollymarker
  var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString3
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng( -37.847516, 144.881589);
  var HollyMarker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng3,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'Newport Workshops in the early 60s'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker3, 'click', function() {
    infowindow3.open(map,HollyMarker3);
  });
// To here.

// Dynon Locomotive Depot
// From here..
// Do not forget the variables that need a number after them below                              
  var contentString4 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Dynon Locomotive Depot Early 60s</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>The Dynon Locomotive Depot</b> was quite easy to obtain access to in the early 1960 period, ' +
      'not so much today. For some reason, this was the only shot I took inside, of B79 and W251.'+
      '<p>Photographs: '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/Interior Dynon early 560s.jpg">'+
      'Interior Dynon Locomotive Depot in the early 60s</a> '+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  // Increment the variables below for each instance of this routine.
  // The variables are: infowindow, myLatLng and Hollymarker
  var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString4
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.805982, 144.930593);
  var HollyMarker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng4,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'Dynon Locomotive Depot in the early 60s'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker4, 'click', function() {
    infowindow4.open(map,HollyMarker4);
  });
// To here.

// North Melbourne Locomotive Depot
// From here..
// Do not forget the variables that need a number after them below                              
  var contentString5 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">North Melbourne Locomotive Depot Early 60s</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>The North Melbourne Locomotive Depot</b> was a magical place, and yet again I failed to ' +
      'photograph it thoroughly while it was around. Just one shot.'+
      '<p>Photographs: '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/Interior North Melbourne early 60s.jpg">'+
      'Interior North Melbourne Locomotive Depot in the early 60s</a> '+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  // Increment the variables below for each instance of this routine.
  // The variables are: infowindow, myLatLng and Hollymarker
  var infowindow5 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString5
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng5 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.808479, 144.940693);
  var HollyMarker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng5,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'North Melbourne Locomotive Depot in the early 60s'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker5, 'click', function() {
    infowindow5.open(map,HollyMarker5);
  });
// To here.

// Puffing Billy Belgrave
// From here..
// Do not forget the variables that need a number after them below                              
  var contentString6 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Puffing Billy at Belgrave in the early 1960s</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>The Puffing Billy Station at Belgrave</b> was was relatively new at this time, and the small ' +
      'engine shed adjacent to the station was the only locomotive accomodation. The kids playing on the track '+
      'would be a no-no these days.'+
      '<p>Photographs: '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/Puffing Billy at Belgrave looking West.jpg">'+
      'Puffing Billy at Belgrave looking West</a> '+
      '<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/Puffing Billy at Belgrave looking down and East.jpg">'+
      'Puffing Billy at Belgrave looking down and East</a> '+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  // Increment the variables below for each instance of this routine.
  // The variables are: infowindow, myLatLng and Hollymarker
  var infowindow6 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString6
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng6 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.907570, 145.356438);
  var HollyMarker6 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng6,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'Puffing Billy Belgrave, 1960s'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker6, 'click', function() {
    infowindow6.open(map,HollyMarker6);
  });
// To here.

// Wonthaggi Line - Bridge Number 1
// From here..
// Do not forget the variables that need a number after them below                              
  var contentString7 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Wonthaggi Line Bridge Number 1</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Wonthaggi Line Bridge Number 1</b> at a distance of 3.9 Kms from Nyora Station ' +
      'Watch this space!! '+
      //'<p><a href="http://www.hollywoodfoundry.com/photo%20collection/Puffing Billy at Belgrave looking down and East.jpg">'+
      //'Bridge 1</a> '+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  // Increment the variables below for each instance of this routine.
  // The variables are: infowindow, myLatLng and Hollymarker
  var infowindow7 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString7
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng7 = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.355080, 145.688647);
  var HollyMarker7 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng7,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'Wonthaggi Line - Bridge Number 1'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker7, 'click', function() {
    infowindow7.open(map,HollyMarker7);
  });
// To here.




// Wonthaggi Line - Bridge Number 2
// 
  var contentString8 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Wonthaggi Line - Bridge Number 2</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Wonthaggi Line - Bridge Number 2</b> is located 4.29 kms from Nyora Railway Station. It is a larger trestle bridge.'+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';
  var infowindow8 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString8
  });
  var image = 'images/camera pointer.png';
  var myLatLng8 = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.357978, 145.686209);
  var HollyMarker8 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng8,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: 'Wonthaggi Line - Bridge Number 2'
  });
 google.maps.event.addListener(HollyMarker8, 'click', function() {
      infowindow8.open(map,HollyMarker8);
  });






}


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please post your code here so that people can read it and see how it works.

Comment: My apologies. The code is quite long, so I did not think it appropriate to load it here, hence the reason I originally provided the link.